# passing null when passing nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, nsstring, nslog

I am defining a NSString in a header file, but it is passing null when I try to log that string from that controller, but logs the value of the variable when if it is not called from the view controller, which is a problem because it also passes null when I try to log it into a different view controller. 
I have found other similar questions, but no solutions seem to be helping, so if you have a solution that would be fantastic.

I have defined it as such in the header file:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface QuestionController : UIViewController
@property(weak, nonatomic) NSString *question;
@end
```

I have called it as such in the main file:

```
#import "QuestionController.h"
@implementation QuestionController
@synthesize question;
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hey"];
    NSLog(@"%@", question);
    QuestionController *questionController = [[QuestionController alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"%@", questionController.question);


}
@end
```

Comment: Why is NSString weak?

Comment: The second log is definitely going to be nil in this case since you didn't initialize the question property in that instance of a QuestionController... But is that first log printing nil as well?

Comment: No particular reason for being weak, but when I change it to strong it doesn't change anything. @rocky

Comment: The first log is not printing nil. @LyndseyScott

Comment: And where do you think you're "passing an NSString"?

Comment: Sorry what exactly do you mean by initializing the question property in the instance of QuestionController, I'm a little new to ios dev. @LyndseyScott

Comment: You have to set the question property of QuestionController.

Comment: I'm passing the NSSting question declared in the header file. @LyndseyScott

Comment: @AriSokolov You haven't passed anything in your current code.

Comment: How do I pass a string into the NSString I declared in the header file then, if the way I am doing it isn't really doing it? Thank you by the way for answering my questions. @LyndseyScott

Comment: No problem... You don't need to "pass" anything though. By simply writing `question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hey"];` you've set that same `question` variable from your .h

Comment: Actually don't synthesize your property though... I recently read that it's considered bad form. Instead of synthesizing just do `self.question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hey"];`

Comment: You also shouldn't use stringWithFormat: when there's nothing to format;  self.question = @"hey" is sufficient.

Comment: I know, I don't necessarily need to pass anything in this controller, but I will need to pass this string assigned in this controller to another controller, and I did a simulation of the passing to another controller in this controller by doing that second way of logging the variable, and indeed I get the same null result in both controllers when I allocate the controller, due to evidently according to you not assigning a value to the variable I declared in the header file, so how do I assign a value to that file? @LyndseyScott

Comment: questionController.question = question;

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
QuestionController *questionController = [[QuestionController alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%@", questionController.question);
```

you're *not* "logging that string from that [current] controller." Instead you've created an *entirely separate* instance of your `QuestionController` (not the same as the current view controller from which you just set `question`) and since you haven't set *its* `question` property at any point, that `NSLog` will print nil.

In your first `NSLog` however, i.e.

```
question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hey"];
NSLog(@"%@", question);
```

you are in fact logging `question` as set in the current instance of your `QuestionController` so it prints as expected.

To set `questionController`'s `question` property to contain `question` though, try:

```
QuestionController *questionController = [[QuestionController alloc]init];
questionController.question = question;
NSLog(@"%@", questionController.question);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned up your code to make it work and at the bottom you will find an explanation.

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface QuestionController : UIViewController
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *question;
@end


#import "QuestionController.h"
@implementation QuestionController

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _question = @"hey";
    NSLog(@"%@", _question);
    QuestionController *questionController = [[QuestionController alloc]init];
    questionController.question = _question;
    NSLog(@"%@", questionController.question);


}
@end
```

There are a few things to take note of.

- NSString *question is now a strong reference, not weak.  If you leave it as weak, things such as question = @"Hello" will not work because there is not strong reference to that string object and it will be deallocated.
- I removed @synthesize, you no longer need to do this unless you are using a much older version of Xcode
- I changed question to _question, you are now accessing the ivar directly, or you can user self.question in that instance to access it through the getter / setter.
- removed the stringWithFormat part, you were not really using that method and doing just @"what you want to write" will suffice.
- You are actually allocating a new version of QuestionController when you do QuestionController *questionController = [[QuestionController alloc]init];  This means that you now have a QuestionController which creates another QuestionController when it loads the view.
- questionController.question = _question; sets the question string object on the new QuestionController object that you create when the view of the first QuestionController loads to the question string that you have in the original QuestionController.

Hope this helps you to understand exactly what was going on in your code.  I am assuming that you are not intentionally trying to create a new QuestionController when the first one loads.  This would also cause some sort of endless loop since every one you create will create another one when you access its view property.